# Why do custom highlights in my vimrc get cleared or reset to default?

Tags: statusline, highlight

I would like to highlight (part of) my statusline with `%1*`, for example:

```
set statusline=%1*%f%0*
highlight User1 ctermbg=0 ctermfg=10 cterm=bold
```

However, this always shows up as "empty" (the default terminal colours):

[image]

If I type `:highlight User1`, it shows `User1 xxx cleared`, and if I type `:highlight User1 ctermbg=0 ctermfg=10 cterm=bold` in the command window, it does seem to work.

How can I put this in my `.vimrc` file?

My full vimrc file I used for testing:

```
set nocompatible
set background=light
colorscheme default
set laststatus=2
set statusline=%1*%f%0*

highlight User1 ctermbg=0 ctermfg=10 cterm=bold
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that many (all?) colorschemes will clear all highlights with `highlight clear` before setting their own colours. For example from `/usr/share/vim/vim74/colors/peachpuff.vim`:

```
" First remove all existing highlighting.
set background=light
hi clear
if exists("syntax_on")
  syntax reset
endif

let colors_name = "peachpuff"

hi Normal guibg=PeachPuff guifg=Black

hi SpecialKey term=bold ctermfg=4 guifg=Blue
" ... Many more highlights follow ...
```

This *also* clears the `User1..9` groups (which doesn't make a lot of sense, IMHO).

The solution is to put custom `User1..9` highlights in the `ColorScheme` autocmd. From [`:help ColorScheme`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#ColorScheme):

> After loading a color scheme. `:colorscheme` The pattern is matched against
>   the colorscheme name. `<afile>` can be used for the name of the actual file
>   where this option was set, and `<amatch>` for the new colorscheme name.

So instead of using a "bare" `highlight` command, use:

```
autocmd ColorScheme *
        \ highlight User1 ctermbg=0 ctermfg=10 cterm=bold |
        \ highlight User2 ctermbg=0 ctermfg=9 cterm=bold
```

If you frequently switch colorschemes, you can even use:

```
autocmd ColorScheme colorscheme_one_name  highlight User1 ctermbg=0 ctermfg=10 cterm=bold
autocmd ColorScheme another_scheme        highlight User1 ctermbg=0 ctermfg=11 cterm=bold
```

to get colours matched to specific colorschemes.