# VIMRC changing Search Highlighting

Tags: vimrc, highlight

My current VIMRC contains the below. I am using the correct colorscheme but it is not accepting my changes for the terminal search highlighting. If I input the :hi command by hand it works. Do I need to use some kind of precursor to hi? set does not work.

```
" Syntax highlight
if &t_Co >= 256 || has("gui_running")
    colorscheme vividchalk
    hi Search cterm=NONE ctermfg=grey ctermbg=blue
endif
```

Comment: I think it's [this issue](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3355/51)?

Comment: Absolutely correct. I guess I will just close this. Thanks!

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate, rather than deleting it. [This makes it easier for other people to find their way to the other question and answer(s)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/166789) ;-)