# How can I fix "missing" syntax highlighting for Python keywords such as "self"?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-python

I'm trying to fix syntax highlighting for python; my colors are different from those in screenshots of what it "should" look like in different vim color schemes. And you can see the difference in comparing .rb (which displays correctly) to .py, which looks like it's off:

[image]

For example, notice how `self` isn't highlighted. (This is in base16, but the comparison would be similar in other color schemes). Generally, it looks like the object syntax highlighting is wrong.

Some things I've tried:

1. Looking at the syntax scripts vim loads; the only difference between .py and .rb in the example below is that, of course, ruby gets indent/ruby.vim and syntax/ruby.vim while python gets indent/python.vim and syntax/python.vim. These are the files that come with homebrew vim.
2. Loading the same files in macvim rather than terminal (iterm2) vim; same problem, the files look exactly the same as in the picture.
3. Adding the [new python.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=790) file. Doesn't solve the problem, even if used as an `.vim/after` script.

Any suggestions are welcome; I've been banging my head on this for hours, and can't figure out why the highlighting isn't working as expected.

Comment: Note that Python doesn't have symbols, and I would strongly recommend you use Python 3 syntax for new code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How syntax highlighting works in brief:

- In `syntax/<filetype>.vim` the syntax rules are defined with the `:syntax` command. This command defines, well, syntax. It says "if text matches this regular expression, it's a string", and so forth. To do so, it assigns a *highlight group*. It does *not* say anything about colours as such.
- `:highlight` says "highlight this group with these colours". This is done in the *colour scheme*, not the syntax file. There are a bunch of default Highlight groups (`String`, `Function`, `Special`, and so forth) which all colour schemes should define.

  You're by no means restricted to these default groups though, and you can create as many groups as you want (but default syntax files typically don't).
- The `indent/<filetype>.vim` file controls automatic indentation. For example for Ruby it says "the line after `def` should increase the indentation level" and "the line after `end` should decrease the indentation one level". It doesn't do anything with colours or syntax highlighting.

---

Why do different programming languages get highlighted different? In part because of the of personal aesthetics and opinions of whoever wrote it. For example in Ruby the `Type` highlight group is used for class names. But it could also have been `Function` or something else. Why is it `Type`? Probably because the author thought that it looked better in his or her colour scheme.

But more importantly, the languages have different semantics and sensibilities. In Ruby, `self` is a special keyword. You can't do `self = "foo"` or `def self()`. These are errors. But this is *not* the case in Python. It's just another variable without any special properties. Doing:

```
x = Object()
x.foo()
```

is really "translated" by Python to:

```
Object.foo(x)
```

The name `self` is just convention (almost universally adopted) but you can name it anything you like; `def x(this):` or `def x(xxx):` are equally valid. You can also use the name `self` anywhere you like; `self = 'foo'` and `def self():` are perfectly fine.

I would argue that `self` shouldn't be highlighted, as it's neither a special keyword, nor a pre-defined variable (like `str`). There is no trace of the word `self` in the syntax file, so it looks like the author of it reasoned the same :-)

---

If you want `self` highlighted you'll have to create a syntax rule for it:

```
:syn keyword pythonBuiltin self
```

The `pythonBuiltin` group name is already defined in the default syntax file and linked to the `Function` highlight group. To use a new highlight group, use something like:

```
:syn keyword pythonSelf self
:highlight def link pythonSelf Special
```

To make these changes you can't just stick 'em in your vimrc file. The syntax file will override it. Instead you'll need to run it *after* the syntax file loads, which you can do in two ways:

1. Use a `FileType` autocmd:

   ```
   augroup python
       autocmd!
       autocmd FileType python
                   \   syn keyword pythonSelf self
                   \ | highlight def link pythonSelf Special
   augroup end
   ```
2. Use the [`after-directory`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#after%2ddirectory), `~/.vim/after/syntax/python.vim`:

   ```
   syn keyword pythonSelf self
   highlight def link pythonSelf Special
   ```

Both methods are effectively the same. Use whichever you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there a way rather than using `Special`, we can use the custom color combination? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, you can define any name you want @TonyMontana; it's just that using standard names makes it work with all colour schemes, as they're defined in there. You can use `highlight pythonSelf [..highlight attributes..]` instead of `highight def link`. Also see [Why do custom highlights in my vimrc get cleared or reset to default?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3355/51).