# How to change vimscript syntax highlighting?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I like the syntax rules and don't need to change them, but what bugs me is that for some reason the author decided to highlight keywords with `Structure` group and function names with `Comment` (or something else). I don't like such inconsistencies. I like keywords, comments and functions highlighted with the same color in every language I work.

The problem is that I can't find the source of this syntax.

Answer (score 2):

As per Carpetsmoker's comment you can put just these `hi` commands in the `syntax` folder per file type, or use an autocmd in your `vimrc` like this:

```
autocmd Filetype * call CustomHighlight()

function! CustomHighlight()
    hi clear Keyword
    hi clear Comment
    hi link Keyword Function
    hi link Comment Function
endfunction
```

You can choose whichever color you like best of the three, but I think this should do what you want.

See `:h hi-link` for more info.

Comment: Doesn't seems to be doing anything.

Comment: @user1685095 You'll need to load this after the syntax file. Put it in `~/.vim/<after>/syntax/<filetype>vim` or in a `autocmd Filetype <filetype>`. See [the last bit of this answer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/8773/51).