# How can I temporarily change to default color scheme?

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme, terminal

I use gnome-termial most of the time, and the Nord colorscheme works well withat hat.

I sometimes also use Tilda (another terminal emulator), and the Nord colorscheme doesn't work well with that!

I've put then `colorscheme nord` in my vimrc file. How can I disable nord in Vim only one time?

**EDIT:-**

```
~$ cat .vimrc
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'vim-scripts/c.vim'

Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'

Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'

Plug 'arcticicestudio/nord-vim'

Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
set number
call plug#end()
if &term =="gnome-256color"
    colorscheme nord
endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`:colorscheme`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3Acolorscheme) command is just like any Vim command. You can run it from Vim's commandline mode after it started: `:colorscheme <name>`.

This applies to almost everything that you can put in your vimrc by the way.

The default colour scheme is named `default`; you can load it with `:colorscheme default`.

---

You can try doing it automatically from your vimrc based on the `$TERM` setting or something else unique in the environment:

```
if &term == "gnome-256color"
    colorscheme nord
endif
```

I guessed the `TERM` name here, as gnome-terminal doesn't want to start on my system for some reason. You'll have to check if this is the correct value.

---

Note that `colorscheme` will clear custom highlights, you need to define those in an autocommand if you have any of them (see [Why do custom highlights in my vimrc get cleared or reset to default?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3355/51)).

Comment: Thanks for the `:colorscheme default`  ,Thats what I needed at the first place.But I have tried  `if &term == "gnome-256color"
    colorscheme nord
endif` And when I execute the vim in terminal,Vim doesn't start in nord by default. I am posting the content of my .vimrc file.