# colorscheme murphy interferes with statusline

Tags: colorscheme, statusline

I do not know if its my term colors or something, but one of my colorschemes (murphy) makes the statusline unreadable

I do not wnat the problem is. Here's my vimrc:

```
"source $HOME/cscope_maps.vim
set nobackup
"set background=dark
"colorscheme peachpuff
"set cursorline
"set cursorcolumn
hi CursorLine cterm=NONE ctermbg=grey ctermfg=black guibg=grey guifg=black
hi CursorColumn cterm=NONE ctermbg=grey ctermfg=black guibg=grey guifg=black

"set lines=27
"set columns=100

" Use Vim settings, rather then Vi settings (much better!).
" This must be first, because it changes other options as a side effect.
set nocompatible

set nu

" allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
set backspace=indent,eol,start

if has("vms")
  set nobackup          " do not keep a backup file, use versions instead
else
  set backup            " keep a backup file
endif
set history=50          " keep 50 lines of command line history
set ruler               " show the cursor position all the time
set rulerformat=%l,%c%V%=%P
set showcmd             " display incomplete commands
set incsearch           " do incremental searching
set ignorecase          " ignore case while searching
"set number              " display line numbers

" For Win32 GUI: remove 't' flag from 'guioptions': no tearoff menu entries
" let &guioptions = substitute(&guioptions, "t", "", "g")

" Don't use Ex mode, use Q for formatting
map Q gq

" In an xterm the mouse should work quite well, thus enable it.
" set mouse=a

" This is an alternative that also works in block mode, but the deleted
" text is lost and it only works for putting the current register.
"vnoremap p "_dp

" Switch syntax highlighting on, when the terminal has colors
" Also switch on highlighting the last used search pattern.
if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
  syntax on
  set hlsearch
endif

" Only do this part when compiled with support for autocommands.
if has("autocmd")

  " Enable file type detection.
  " Use the default filetype settings, so that mail gets 'tw' set to 72,
  " 'cindent' is on in C files, etc.
  " Also load indent files, to automatically do language-dependent indenting.
  filetype plugin indent on

  " Put these in an autocmd group, so that we can delete them easily.
  augroup vimrcEx
  au!

  " For all text files set 'textwidth' to 78 characters.
  autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=78

  " When editing a file, always jump to the last known cursor position.
  " Don't do it when the position is invalid or when inside an event handler
  " (happens when dropping a file on gvim).
  autocmd BufReadPost *
    \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
    \   exe "normal g`\"" |
    \ endif

  augroup END

else

  set autoindent                " always set autoindenting on

endif " has("autocmd")

set cindent shiftwidth=3

" Symbol Find all references to the token under cursor
nmap <F2> <ESC>:scs find s <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
" Global Find global definitions of the token under cursor
nmap <F3> <ESC>:scs find g <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
" calls Find all calls to the function name under cursor
nmap <F4> <ESC>:scs find c <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
" text Find all instances of the text  under cursor
nmap <F6> <ESC>:scs find t <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
" egrep search for the word under cursor
nmap <F7> <ESC>:scs find e <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
" open file name under cursor
nmap <F8> <ESC>:scs find f <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
" find files that include the filenames under cursor
nmap <F9> <ESC>:scs find i <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR>$<CR>
" find functions that function under the cursor calls
nmap <F10> <ESC>:scs find d <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>

" Symbol Find all references to the token under cursor
nmap <C-F2> <ESC>:vert split cs find s <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
" Global Find global definitions of the token under cursor
nmap <C-F3> <ESC>:vert split cs find g <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
" calls Find all calls to the function name under cursor
nmap <C-F5> <ESC>:vert split cs find c <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
" text Find all instances of the text  under cursor
nmap <C-F6> <ESC>:vert split cs find t <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
" egrep search for the word under cursor
nmap <C-F7> <ESC>:vert split cs find e <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
" open file name under cursor
nmap <C-F8> <ESC>:vert split cs find f <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
" find files that include the filenames under cursor
nmap <C-F9> <ESC>:vert split cs find i <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR>$<CR>
" find functions that function under the cursor calls

nmap <F10> <ESC>:scs find d <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
nmap <C-\>s :cs find s <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
nmap <C-\>g :cs find g <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
nmap <C-\>c :cs find c <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
nmap <C-\>t :cs find t <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
nmap <C-\>e :cs find e <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
nmap <C-\>f :cs find f <C-R>=expand("<cfile>")<CR><CR>
nmap <C-\>i :cs find i ^<C-R>=expand("<cfile>")<CR>$<CR>
nmap <C-\>d :cs find d <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>

" Convenient command to see the difference between the current buffer and the
" file it was loaded from, thus the changes you made.
command DiffOrig vert new | set bt=nofile | r # | 0d_ | diffthis
                \ | wincmd p | diffthis

set vb
set ts=4
set autoindent
set number
highlight StatusLine cterm=bold ctermfg=Green ctermbg=Black
:set statusline=%f
:set statusline+=%c
set laststatus=2
colorscheme murphy
syntax enable
set cindent
":fixdel
"set backspace=eol,start
set nocompatible
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set ignorecase
set smartcase
set incsearch
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set hlsearch
set nolist
"set listchars=eol:$,tab:>-,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<,space:.
set listchars=eol:$,tab:>-,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<
:noremap <F12> :set nolist!<CR>
" Press F11 to toggle highlighting on/off, and show current value.
:noremap <F11> :set hlsearch! hlsearch?<CR>

set gfn=Consolas:h13:cANSI:qDRAFT
if &diff
    :noremap <F5> [c
    :noremap <F6> ]c
    syntax off
    highlight DiffAdd    cterm=bold ctermfg=Black ctermbg=Green gui=none guifg=bg guibg=Red
    highlight DiffDelete cterm=bold ctermfg=Black ctermbg=Magenta gui=none guifg=bg guibg=Red
    highlight DiffChange cterm=bold ctermfg=Black ctermbg=Blue gui=none guifg=bg guibg=Red
    highlight DiffText   cterm=bold ctermfg=Black ctermbg=Cyan gui=none guifg=bg guibg=Red
    highlight StatusLine cterm=bold ctermfg=Green ctermbg=Black
endif
retab
autocmd BufEnter * silent! lcd %:p:h
nmap <F12> <ESC>:set list!<C-R><CR>
"nmap <C-F12>:set list!$<CR>
```

Statusline is ok with other colorschemes like elflord or desert. Please help

Comment: Hi, welcome to Vi/Vim SE. It's not a great idea to just dump a big vimrc file here without some indication that you tried to debug it yourself or at least tried to narrow things down some (e.g. eliminate lines that clearly have no relation to the problem). Fortunately, there's a nice post that can help you with such endeavors: [How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003) . . Cheers.

Comment: Possibly related : https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3355/10604

Comment: @D.BenKnoble That helps in a way however that messes up the entire colorscheme in some way. I just want to modify the way the statusline gets displayed within that colorscheme

Comment: @BLayer thanks for the welcome and your suggestion. I've tried fiddling around with laststatus but it wouldn't help and I do not have a whole lot of time as of now to fiddle with vimrc. But I'd definitely try to get back to this once im a bit more relaxed from work